# Python MySQL query output

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I am trying to query a MySQL table to get a specific user type depending on their email

```
import pymysql

conn= pymysql.connect(host='<ip>',user='<user>',password=<pass>',db='<db>')

a = conn.cursor()

a.execute("SELECT `type` FROM `users` WHERE `email` LIKE '<email>';")

data = a.fetchone()

print(data)
```

The output is `('user',)`, how can I get the output to be just `user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returned a tuple. So check if it has correct number of elements (1) and extract element desired:

```
if len(data) == 1:
    print data[0]
```